# CSV parsing error with particular row[8]: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to fetch row values from CSV files, everything works as expected except `row[8]`. But same row works as `row[7]` if I delete any other row before it.

```
comment = row[8]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the sample CSV:

```
190,3391d5ae,,Host-1,FuelNode-1,"http,tcp-8000",False,,created on - 6/10/14
192,25dbbf4c,sam,"vlan85,vlan86","Srv1,Srv2",dhcp-relay,False,25-10-2018,
```

> Please note there are few fields do not have values present or blank.

Here is the code i have written.

```
outFiles = os.listdir('datastore/csv_out_files')
ext = "*.csv"  
for csvoutfile in outFiles:
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(csvoutfile, ext):
     with open('datastore/csv_out_files/'+ csvoutfile) as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        headers = next(rows)
        for row in rows:
            uid = row[1]
            name = row[2]
            source = row[3]
            destination = row[4]
            service = row[5]
            enabled = row[6]
            use_date = row[7]
            comment = row[8]

            if not use_date:
                use_date = "Never Used"

            print "              UID:", (uid)
            print "             Name:", (name)
            print "           Source:", (source)
            print "      Destination:", (destination)
            print "          Service:", (service)
            print "          Enabled:", (enabled)
            print "        Last Used:", (use_date)
            print "  Additional Info:", (comment)
```

Please help me, I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: Working as intended for me in Python3.6

Comment: Yes it should work but getting above error. i am using python 2.7.5. Dont know whats wrong.

Comment: I've just tried it in Python 2.7.15 and it's working for me. I'll try to test it in 2.7.5.